# Screen Time blocks Google websites because YouTube is restricted

Tags: macos, screen-time

I'm using Screen Time's feature to block a website:

```
System Preferences -> Screen Time -> Content & Privacy -> Limit Adult Websites -> Customise... -> Restricted -> https://youtube.com/
```

Funny thing is, when I try to visit `google.com` or any of its subdomains (`drive.google.com`, `calendar.google.com`), I get this:

[image]

I looked at the Network tab, but there I only see requests to the `google.com` domain, but no requests to `youtube.com`. And what's even funnier is that when I visit `youtube.com` by entering it in the address bar of the browser, it loads without any problems. Do you have any idea why Screen Time behaves like this and how to fix it?

Comment: This is because google goes to youtube.com to check if you're logged in. I'm commenting rather than posting a solution since I don't know the fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that Google, as part of its single sign-on (SSO) process, also logs you into YouTube. For most of the Google applications, it can set cookies that are valid on `*.google.com`, but for YouTube, it redirects you to `https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID` with a sign-on token; you can see this URL briefly flash up when you log in.

It's this redirect that's tripping up your filter. As described in other answers, you can restrict your filter to `www.youtube.com`, or you might be able to explicitly whitelist `accounts.youtube.com`.

Comment: Hey Chryls, thanks for the answer. Yeah, that's what I also thought. The thing that's confusing to me is I don't see the request in the network tab.

Comment: Thanks for getting the specifics - I couldn’t see this in the debugger either.

Comment: @Alexander Under the Inspector options, check "Common Preferences→Enable persistent logs". Firefox will clear the network history whenever you navigate to a new page (as through a redirect).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The idea is to show you how a site embeds another so screen time appears to be working as intended.

Fix this by white listing the sites Google embeds in the sites you need to ask them to change how they construct their web sites. Or choose a different search provider. (Or don’t use Google sites in general).

[image]

This is highly confusing in practice since when the OS uses a search provider, you don’t always see the network requests. Try changing your search provider to duck duck go and disabling web previews in your browser app / system settings to get an easier set of variables to juggle while you sort out which places you want to block is how I pick these issues apart (in general).

The above picture is how I set up Safari for easier triage of blocked sites. You may need other settings if you use third party browsers or to understand if they respect the Safari settings.

Comment: Hey @bmike. Sorry, but I didn't quite understand your answer. :) Could you rephrase "Fix this by white listing the sites Google embeds in the sites you need to ask them to change how they construct their web sites." Also, I'm not using Google as search provider, but I do need Google Calendar and Drive for work.

Comment: Google programmed this @Alexander when you go to calendar, it’s calling out to YouTube servers or servers that serve both and Apple is letting you know the site is pulling your cookies or data or beacons from a blocked site. Google analytics are the reason for this being complicated from my experience

Answer (score 2):

Your filter is probably too broad: `https://youtube.com` blocks `https://<anythinghere>.YouTube.com`.

Try changing your Screen Time filter to specifically block `https://www.youtube.com` if your intention is to limit access to YouTube videos. IIRC there is an API or Analytics site that is visited to get some resources, etc.

I've just tried this and didn't receive any blocks from Screen Time.

[This article](https://osxdaily.com/2020/07/14/how-to-block-websites-on-mac-with-screen-time/) also specifically adds [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) .

Alternatively, set the Time Limit for YouTube to 1 minute; this prevents the problem occurring and probably achieves your intention - stop watching YouTube videos.

Comment: Hey @JBRWilkinson you say the filter is too broad. The question is - why would `calendar.google.com` make any requests to `https://<anythinghere>.YouTube.com`. Also, I don't see these requests in the network tab, that's what baffles me.

Comment: Indeed blacklisting `https://www.youtube.com` helped block youtube.com, however I still can't visit calendar.google.com.

Comment: @Alexander Google doesn’t want you to block things so they make several products use the same servers. You may have to be all in with Google and that includes YouTube